# align label and text field in a same line rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have an html like below where I have 3 text fields and labels for them.

```
<p class='field'>
  <%= form.label :points %>
  <%= form.text_field :coupon_code, :class => 'form-control payment-new' %>
  <%= button_tag "Apply", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success primary payment-coupon payment-coupon-mobile ',id: 'apcode' %>
</p>


<p class='field'>
  <%= form.label :coupon_code %>
  <%= form.text_field :coupon_code, :class => 'form-control payment-new' %>
  <%= button_tag "Apply", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success primary payment-coupon',id: 'apcode' %>
</p>
<p class='field'>

<%= form.label :gift_code %>
<%= form.text_field :gift_code, value: nil, :class => 'form-control payment-new' %>
<%= button_tag "Apply", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success primary payment-code',id: '' %>
</p>
```

I want the label to come first and then the text field at the same position (CSS).

My 3 label names are

Points, Coupon Code and Gift Code.

I want my all 3 text fields to be at the same space from my label.

I am unable to get that.

Below is the CSS I am using.

```
 .payment-new{
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 50% !important;
 }

 .payment-coupon{
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
 }

 .payment-code{
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 55px ;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
 }
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: why not use a table?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/6u1Ljdyb/

Comment: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6u1Ljdyb/1/) is my doubt.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. Use a [horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4PfTyOtENf)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked for me with slight modifications. Thanks @cory

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `label`

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Example Snippet**

```css
.payment-new{
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 50% !important;
 }

 .payment-coupon{
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
 }

 .payment-code{
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 55px ;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
 }
 label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<p class='field'>
  <label>Label 1</label>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Button 1</button>
</p>


<p class='field'>
  <label>Another Label</label>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Button 2</button>
</p>
```